C# HttpClient: Why does my request return a 404 error after setting headers from sessionHeaders?
I'm working on a C# application that makes HTTP requests to a server to check for available dates using HttpClient. I have two different approaches to setting up the headers for the request, but only one of them works. The other approach returns a 404 error.
Here's a simplified version of my code for context.
Working code
This code sets headers using sessionHeaders and additional headers:
private Dictionary<string, string> ExtractHeaders(HttpResponseMessage response)
{
    var cookies = ExtractRelevantCookies(response);

    var html = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

    // Parse HTML to extract the CSRF token
    var doc = new HtmlDocument();
    doc.LoadHtml(html);

    var csrfTokenNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//meta[@name='csrf-token']");
    var csrfToken = csrfTokenNode?.Attributes["content"].Value;

    var baseUri = some url; 

    // Return the headers as a dictionary
    return new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "Cookie", cookies },
            { "X-CSRF-Token", csrfToken },
            { "Referer", baseUri },
            { "Referrer-Policy", "strict-origin-when-cross-origin" },
            { "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" },
            { "Cache-Control", "no-store" },
            { "Connection", "keep-alive" }
        };
}

private async Task<DateTime?> CheckDate(Dictionary<string, string> sessionHeaders)
{
    var url = $"{some url}";

    _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
    AddHeaders(sessionHeaders, _httpClient);

    _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");

    var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(url);
    var responseData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    return null; 
}

Non-working code
In the second approach, I set headers manually via DefaultRequestHeaders, but this leads to a http 404 error:
private Dictionary<string, string> ExtractHeaders(HttpResponseMessage response)
{
    var cookies = ExtractRelevantCookies(response);
    var html = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

    var doc = new HtmlDocument();
    doc.LoadHtml(html);

    var csrfTokenNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//meta[@name='csrf-token']");
    var csrfToken = csrfTokenNode?.Attributes["content"].Value;

    return new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "Cookie", cookies },
            { "X-CSRF-Token", csrfToken }
        };
}

private async Task<DateTime?> CheckDate(Dictionary<string, string> sessionHeaders)
{
    var url = $"some url";

    _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();

    // Manually add sessionHeaders
    foreach (var header in sessionHeaders)
    {
        _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(header.Key, header.Value);
    }

    // Add additional headers
    _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Referrer", some url);
    _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Referrer-Policy", "strict-origin-when-cross-origin");
    _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36");
    _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.CacheControl = new CacheControlHeaderValue { NoStore = true };
    _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Connection.Add("keep-alive");

    _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");

    var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(url);
    var responseData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    return null;
}

The only difference between the two approaches seems to be how I'm adding headers from sessionHeaders. In both cases, "Cookie" is included in sessionHeaders.
When using the first approach (AddHeaders method), everything works as expected. But in the second approach, where I manually add headers, I get a http 404 error.
What could be causing the 404 error in the second approach? Are there any potential pitfalls when setting headers manually in HttpClient?
private string ExtractRelevantCookies(HttpResponseMessage 
 response)
    {
        var cookies = response.Headers.GetValues("Set-Cookie");
        var parsedCookies = ParseCookies(cookies);
        return $"session={parsedCookies["session_session"]}";
    }


Hi chatay, I have test your code, since we don't what is ExtractRelevantCookies, and we can't reproduce the issue. We need more code to reproduce the issue.

And you also can capture the http trace via fiddler, then we can compare the difference.

@JasonPan I updated the code added the ExtractRelevantCookies

Still missing some code, like ParseCookies. If you can provide a sample, we can help you fix it soon.
